# JavaFX labels won't show up

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to practice with BorderPanes, which so far has been a nightmare. I have tried to get my label to just show up in the window with no avail. Any ideas?

```
Label arrayLabel = new Label("NUMBERS");
BorderPane.setAlignment(arrayLabel, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

TextField search = new TextField();
Button btn = new Button("search");
HBox searchbox = new HBox(2);
searchbox.getChildren().addAll(search, btn);
searchbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

BorderPane root = new BorderPane(arrayLabel);
root.setPrefSize(600, 600);
root.setCenter(searchbox);
```

Answer (score 4):

A `BorderPane` can only have one node in any region. (That node, of course, could be a parent containing arbitrary numbers of other nodes.) The [constructor taking a single parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html#BorderPane-javafx.scene.Node-) treats that parameter as the node to be displayed in the center.

So

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane(arrayLabel);
```

is equivalent to

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
root.setCenter(arrayLabel);
```

When you subsequently (immediately) then call

```
root.setCenter(searchbox);
```

the center node is *replaced* by `searchbox`, so `arraylabel` is no longer part of the `BorderPane`.

It's not really clear what you intend here: you are essentially trying to put two different UI components (`arrayLabel` and `searchbox`) into the same region of the same `BorderPane`. There's no information (provided either to us, or to the poor `BorderPane` who is trying to position these nodes) as to how you want these two components positioned relative to each other. What are you actually trying to achieve, in terms of how you want these laid out?